# Having problems crystal report and IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have developed project by using asp.net and SQL server 2008 R2 for reporting. I have used crystal report 11 in visual studio, and i used crystal 13 for vs after publish this.
When i am going to set into IIS in different machine. This error occur:

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the folder of aspnet_client is existed in wwwroot folder
2. Make sure you've already installed the crystal reports dlls also

Comment: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.dll CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll                         CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll                                           CrystalDecisions.Web.dll  ..i have attached above .ddl file but noting change  probllem is remain same

Comment: yes then are you sure there is a folder named aspnet_client in wwwroot folder ?